# Running python script which accesses nltk wordnet on WAMP

Tags: php, python, wamp, nltk

I've been having some major issues with running anything nltk-related.

**What works:**

```
 running python script with nltk on my pc
 running python script without nltk from a page on my server which is accessed remotely or locally
```

**What doesn't work:**

```
 running python script with nltk from a php script on my server which is accessed remotely or locally
```

**What I have tried:**

```
 converting the python script into an exe
 running python from c++ which is run from php
 playing around with php.ini file
```

Basically my problem is that if I exec a python file which contains nltk related code from php, something wrong happens, I cant know what, I try printing to a file from the python script, it creates the file, but it stays empty, thats all I can say.

Currently, I'm also trying to set up cgi so I can try running the python script from perl or use python as cgi directly, but encountering problems with getting cgi to work.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

After much brain-pain, I had to divert to using php for doing my lemmatization.

[PhPMorphy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmorphy/) did its job quite well as a replacement of nltk.